# CType html - prevent JavaScript

Tags: typo3

I found no solution to prevent JavaScript inline code entered in CType html in the backend. Is there any configuration setting to prevent JavaScript in this CType?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no solution out of the box. I see the following solutions to solve it:

- Avoid HTML element or restrict it to admins only
- Create proper content elements which allow an editor to solve the real problem
- Create a ViewHelper which does the filtering but **be aware** that filtering HTML out of HTML is really hard - maybe http://htmlpurifier.org/ could help there